# Something in for-loop breaks down after 17 loops

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have the following for-loop:

```
i = 1
y = 4
for column in new_columns:
    df[column] = (df['column1'] * (1+G1)**i * (df['ER1'] - df['ER2']) \
                    * df['column2'] * (1+ df['Column3'])**i + df['column1'] \
                    * (1+G1)**i * df['E2'] * df['Column2'] * (1+ df['Column3'])**i \
                    * (1 - ER2) * df['Column4'])/ (1 + df['ER4'])**y
    i += 1
    y += 1
```

I noticed a bizarre kink in a graph made of the new columns and I decided to double-check the calculation by running the same thing in MS Excel. The ratio between the Python and Excel columns is 1 until loop number 17. On the 18th loop, the ratio jumps to 1.0249 (Python produces 2.5 % higher numbers) and stays there until the last loop (30). There is no kink on the graph produced in MS Excel. Any wise thoughts?

Comment: Are any of your numbers floats? It could be a floating point error

Comment: You need to rewrite this question so that it forms a [mcve]. I’m pretty sure a kink in a graph is not a technical term everyone knows. We need to be able to recreate the error with data, which is not possible here. Maybe drop the loop and show us iteration 17 or so.

Comment: Excel and python versions?  Most likely one is 32 bit and the other is 64 bit and you're getting floating-point errors.

Comment: Thanks guys, I think you're right that it has to do with floating point precision. However, both my Excel and Python (3.6) are 64 bit. I have stored the numbers as float64 in Python, as well. I am just learning about 'Decimal' and 'Fraction', but I have not succeeded in converting all of the numbers. I get `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'float' and 'decimal.Decimal'` even after having converted everything into Decimal.

Comment: Update: I get exactly the same behaviour with `np.longdouble`

Answer (score 0):

After spending about 8 hours on this, I finally noticed that I had a duplicate in `new columns`which obviously didn't show up on the resulting dataframe and hence the difference with Excel. Sorry guys.